# Solution for a system of non linear equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

$  x =  \phi(x +  t)$ is the system of non-linear equation which I need to solve for $x$.

Here $x$, $t$, $\phi(.)$ are vectors all having dimension $n$.

How to solve this system using Newton's method.

I have the closed form for the Jacobian and Hessian of $\phi$.